Git add: Error No such file or directory and unable to index MainActivity.kt
Using Flutter Windows 11, checked that file 'MainActivity.kt' exists in the proper path yet while using git add . for first commit to repo, got errors:
warning: in the working copy of '.metadata', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
error: open("android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/j/con/con/MainActivity.kt"): No such file or directory
error: unable to index file 'android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/j/con/con/MainActivity.kt'
fatal: adding files failed

Tried on both VS Code and Android Studio Terminal
